# How to fix FTP Login Error?

Tags: ftp, windows-server-2008-r2, iis, filezilla, plesk

After setting up FTP account for user the following message appears after trying to login to Filezilla:

> Response: 530 User cannot log in, home directory inaccessible. Error:
>   Critical error: Could not connect to server.

I do have FTP accounts that are accessible, but somehow any new user account is denied access now. The user has been given rights to read and write to the directory/folder and credentials are correct. What could possibly be the issue that would cause this error?

Note: FTP Authentication is set as Basic Authentication - Enabled and Anonymous Authentication - Disabled.

Comment: "Home directory inaccessible" - so, have you setup a home directory for a new user? Attach a print screen of Filezilla user settings...

Comment: I assume you are not connecting *"to FileZilla [Server]"*, but connecting *"using FileZilla [client]"*, right? Because *"530 User cannot log in, home directory inaccessible"* is actually an error message of IIS FTP server. See [FTP Error 530, User cannot log in, home directory inaccessible](http://serverfault.com/q/190889/168875).

Comment: Yes, the user will be using Filezilla client.